# QTAgent32.exe has stopped working

Tags: .net, visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, resharper

I have a VS2012/.NET4.5 solution with huge number of unit tests

When running All unit tests from solution I am randomly getting "QTAgent32.exe has stopped working" error message and unit tests hangs at this point.

My unit tests are actually MSTest and I run them using Resharper menu from VS. Resharper Edition is 7.1.3, not sure if it matters. VS 2012 SP 3

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Eventually I found the reason

One piece of code was written incorrectly and under some curcumstances caused endless recursion and stack overflow. So if you getting the same error "**QTAgent32.exe has stopped working**" try to check what is your call stak at this point.

Comment: Thank you :) Same this here

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem, so I will present the solution here for anyone else with the same problem.

I would get "QTAgent32.exe has stopped working" whenever trying to run any unit test. This started after I reorganized my solution by pulling out some code into a class library.

This was for a .NET 3.5 solution in VS Premium 2012, update 4.

The fix in the end was to delete the suo file. (This is a hidden file, by the way.)

Comment: This solved the problem temporarily, but it came back again. I bit the bullet and switched to xUnit.net, which has its own test runner. (Which means QTAgent isn't used.) It took me one day to port all of my 588 tests. Everything works fine now.

Answer (score 2):

FWIW: My solution in VS2012 was to remove my `TraceAndTestImpact.testsettings` file in the solutions directory. (*possibly* together with removing `MySolutionName.sln.DotSettings.user` and running with elevated privileges)

If you get the following,

```
An exception occurred while test discoverer 'MSTestDiscoverer' was loading tests.
Exception: An error occurred while initializing the settings provider named 'MSTest'.
Error: The test settings file C:\....\TraceAndTestImpact.testsettings, specified in
the MSTestAdapter settings, is not available. Either access to the file is denied or
the file does not exist. Ensure that the test settings file is available and try again.
```

try loading the solution with elevated privileges. To add insult to injury no new `TraceAndTestImpact.testsettings` file is created.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and the problem was some tests that had `Thread.Sleep` inside a `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`.

I've found where the error was after removing the test configuration file: **my-project.testsettings**. Deleting this file stopped the *QTAgent32.exe has stopped working* message and started showing the exception about the thread being aborted.

Answer (score 0):

Same happened to me after rebooting my PC, running Visual Studio Professional 2013 Update 2. Even the simplest test failed before it was entered and the message "QTAgent32.exe has stopped working" came up.

Running Visual Studio as Administrator solved the problem for me. Probably only removing the symptom not the cause, but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had an `async` test that had a cleanup after the `assert` statement. The test was always green (passed) but after every execution the `'QTAgent32.exe has stopped working'` error appeared.

After the `assert` statement I called a method on an object that was `null`. I think it's due to the behavior of the `async` test that the `NullReferenceException` was swallowed.

I found the issue by simply debugging the test. Maybe this will help someone in the future.